# SQL DateTime Overflow Using Multiple LINQ Statements

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have the following issue.

In the below code block the first time through an if statement fires off and everything goes fine. The second time through the formData.Where errors out with an SQL DateTime overflow. The value being pulled back is a string and has nothing to do with dates. The record that is being referenced does have a date, but its the current day. I have changed the order that these if statements fire in and it doesn't matter which one is first or second. the second one always throws the exception.

```
foreach (string riderGroup in riderGroups)
            {
                if (riderGroup == "69")
                {
                    var deathRiderValue = formData.Where(x => x.FieldName == "rider69Value").Select(x => x.FieldValue).Single().ToString();
                    var rider = _riderDataService.GetRiderById(Convert.ToInt32(deathRiderValue));
                    premiumAccount.AddRider(new PolicyRider { Rider = rider, PremiumAccount = premiumAccount, Policy = policy });                        
                }
                if (riderGroup == "211")
                {
                    var gmabRiderValue = formData.Where(x => x.FieldName == "rider211Value").Select(x => x.FieldValue).Single().ToString();
                    var rider = _riderDataService.GetRiderById(Convert.ToInt32(gmabRiderValue));
                    premiumAccount.AddRider(new PolicyRider { Rider = rider, PremiumAccount = premiumAccount, Policy = policy });
                }
                if (riderGroup == "96")
                {
                    var giveawayPromoValue = formData.Where(x => x.FieldName == "rider96Value").Select(x => x.FieldValue).Single().ToString();
                    if (giveawayPromoValue == "1")
                    {
                        var rider = _riderDataService.GetRiderById(5);
                        premiumAccount.AddRider(new PolicyRider { Rider = rider, PremiumAccount = premiumAccount, Policy = policy });
                    }
                }
            }
```

Any ideas?

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlTypeException: SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.

Here is the call stack:

```
    [SqlTypeException: SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TdsExecuteRPC(SqlCommand cmd, _SqlRPC[] rpcArray, Int32 timeout, Boolean inSchema, SqlNotificationRequest notificationRequest, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean isCommandProc, Boolean sync, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 startRpc, Int32 startParam) +7688
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest) +2026
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite) +375
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method) +53
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) +161
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +41
   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader() +14
   NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher.ExecuteReader(IDbCommand cmd) +347
   NHibernate.Id.InsertSelectDelegate.ExecuteAndExtract(IDbCommand insert, ISessionImplementor session) +77
   NHibernate.Id.Insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.PerformInsert(SqlCommandInfo insertSQL, ISessionImplementor session, IBinder binder) +112
   NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Insert(Object[] fields, Boolean[] notNull, SqlCommandInfo sql, Object obj, ISessionImplementor session) +283
   NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Insert(Object[] fields, Object obj, ISessionImplementor session) +391
   NHibernate.Action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.Execute() +283
   NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.Execute(IExecutable executable) +48
   NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractSaveEventListener.PerformSaveOrReplicate(Object entity, EntityKey key, IEntityPersister persister, Boolean useIdentityColumn, Object anything, IEventSource source, Boolean requiresImmediateIdAccess) +839
   NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractSaveEventListener.PerformSave(Object entity, Object id, IEntityPersister persister, Boolean useIdentityColumn, Object anything, IEventSource source, Boolean requiresImmediateIdAccess) +579
   NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractSaveEventListener.SaveWithGeneratedId(Object entity, String entityName, Object anything, IEventSource source, Boolean requiresImmediateIdAccess) +278
   NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.SaveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(SaveOrUpdateEvent event) +118
   NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.EntityIsTransient(SaveOrUpdateEvent event) +219
   NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.PerformSaveOrUpdate(SaveOrUpdateEvent event) +232
   NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.OnSaveOrUpdate(SaveOrUpdateEvent event) +347
   NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.FireSaveOrUpdate(SaveOrUpdateEvent event) +193
   NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.SaveOrUpdate(String entityName, Object obj) +155
   NHibernate.Engine.SaveUpdateCascadingAction.Cascade(IEventSource session, Object child, String entityName, Object anything, Boolean isCascadeDeleteEnabled) +106
   NHibernate.Engine.Cascade.CascadeToOne(Object parent, Object child, IType type, CascadeStyle style, Object anything, Boolean isCascadeDeleteEnabled) +238
   NHibernate.Engine.Cascade.CascadeAssociation(Object parent, Object child, IType type, CascadeStyle style, Object anything, Boolean isCascadeDeleteEnabled) +101
   NHibernate.Engine.Cascade.CascadeProperty(Object parent, Object child, IType type, CascadeStyle style, Object anything, Boolean isCascadeDeleteEnabled) +135
   NHibernate.Engine.Cascade.CascadeCollectionElements(Object parent, Object child, CollectionType collectionType, CascadeStyle style, IType elemType, Object anything, Boolean isCascadeDeleteEnabled) +667
   NHibernate.Engine.Cascade.CascadeCollection(Object parent, Object child, CascadeStyle style, Object anything, CollectionType type) +292
   NHibernate.Engine.Cascade.CascadeAssociation(Object parent, Object child, IType type, CascadeStyle style, Object anything, Boolean isCascadeDeleteEnabled) +188
   NHibernate.Engine.Cascade.CascadeProperty(Object parent, Object child, IType type, CascadeStyle style, Object anything, Boolean isCascadeDeleteEnabled) +135
   NHibernate.Engine.Cascade.CascadeOn(IEntityPersister persister, Object parent, Object anything) +588
   NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractFlushingEventListener.CascadeOnFlush(IEventSource session, IEntityPersister persister, Object key, Object anything) +130
   NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractFlushingEventListener.PrepareEntityFlushes(IEventSource session) +363
   NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractFlushingEventListener.FlushEverythingToExecutions(FlushEvent event) +203
   NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.OnAutoFlush(AutoFlushEvent event) +144
   NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.AutoFlushIfRequired(ISet`1 querySpaces) +289
   NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.List(IQueryExpression queryExpression, QueryParameters queryParameters, IList results) +206
   NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.List(IQueryExpression queryExpression, QueryParameters parameters) +227
   NHibernate.Impl.ExpressionQueryImpl.List() +146
   NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.ExecuteQuery(NhLinqExpression nhLinqExpression, IQuery query, NhLinqExpression nhQuery) +72
   NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression) +93
   NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression) +50
   System.Linq.Queryable.Single(IQueryable`1 source) +211
   FrontOffice.HelperExtensions.FormProcessHelper.AddOnPremiumProcess(Int32 id) in c:\Users\hprentiss\Documents\SI Project\T3 Core\Dev\FrontOffice\HelperExtensions\FormProcessHelper.cs:314
   FrontOffice.Areas.NewBusiness.Controllers.ImportFormsController.ProcessFormAddOnPremium(Int32 id) in c:\Users\hprentiss\Documents\SI Project\T3 Core\Dev\FrontOffice\Areas\NewBusiness\Controllers\ImportFormsController.cs:135
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +161
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +19
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +209
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass42.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__41() +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +58
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass39.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__33() +57
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49() +223
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49() +223
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49() +223
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49() +223
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +58
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20() +24
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +102
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +58
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +16
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +58
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +54
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +16
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +58
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +25
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +16
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +58
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +11
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9724953
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

The FormData class

```
public class FormData : Entity
{
    public virtual int FormSubmissionID { get; set; }
    public virtual string FieldName { get; set; }
    public virtual string FieldValue { get; set; }

    public FormData()
    {

    }
}
```

The Entity Class it inherits

```
[Serializable]
public class Entity
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? DateModified { get; set; }
    public virtual int? ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    public Entity()
    {
        IsActive = true;
        DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
    }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ID != 0)
        {
            Entity obj2 = obj as Entity;
            return ((obj2 != null) && (ID == obj2.ID));
        }
        return base.Equals(obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (ID != 0) ? ID.GetHashCode() : base.GetHashCode();
    }

    public virtual void Deactivate()
    {
        IsActive = false;
    }

    public virtual void EncryptFields()
    {
    }

    public virtual object AddHistoryRecord()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

FormData Map

```
public class FormDataMap : BaseMap<FormData>
{
    public FormDataMap ()
    {
        Table("tblFormData");
        Id(x => x.ID, "FormDataID");
        Map(x => x.FormSubmissionID);
        Map(x => x.FieldName);
        Map(x => x.FieldValue);
    }        
}
```

Entity Map

```
public BaseMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.ID);
        MapEntity();
        Map(x => x.IsActive).Not.Nullable().Default("1");
        Map(x => x.DateCreated).Not.Nullable().Default("getdate()");
        Map(x => x.DateModified);
        Map(x => x.ModifiedBy);
    }
    protected virtual void MapEntity()
    {
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean `DateTime overflow`? Where in all this code is `DateTime` used? What is the *actual* error? A `datetime` field wouldn't allow you to store an invalid value at all, so how can there be an overflow? Are you storing dates as strings perhaps and trying to cast them to `DateTime`? That's a serious bug in itself.

Comment: Post the *full* exception including its callstack. You can get it with `Exception.ToString()`. Also post the code that actually raises the error. What you posted here doesn't seem to use dates anywhere

Comment: Added the exception and stack trace

Comment: You are probably passing a `0001-01-01` value to a `datetime` field but, how did a `Single` call result in an **INSERT** statement? What's going on inside the properties ??? Does any getter in your classes try to insert data somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Your exception defines what's going on in "fromdate" variable, it is setting null. Use breakpoint there, trace value within "fromdate", it must not be less than 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and not greater than 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.
This error occurs if you trying to set variable of type DateTime to null. Declare the variable as nullable, i.e. `DateTime?` . This will solve the problem.

Comment: There are 2 columns that have to due with DateTime. 1 is DateCreated which we don't allow to be null and a DateModified which is nullable already.

Comment: fromdate is a DateTime type?

Comment: There is no fromdate. I'm not sure where you are seeing that. There is a FormData class that inherits from an Entity class that has DateCreated and DateModified.

Comment: Share that class implementation.

Comment: Added the classes and maps

Answer (score 0):

This *should* be a comment but it's too long:

Like @M Adeel Khalid said in his answer, the *most common* condition resulting in this exception is trying to put a value in a SQL Server `datetime` column that is **valid** for C# but **invalid** for SQL Server.  **Where that might be happening** is the key, but it is very hard to tell from what you've provided.

1. What line of your pasted code is the exception occurring on?
2. What about those 2 line numbers in the stack trace (pasted below)?

FrontOffice.HelperExtensions.FormProcessHelper.AddOnPremiumProcess(Int32 id) in c:\Users\hprentiss\Documents\SI Project\T3 Core\Dev\FrontOffice\HelperExtensions\FormProcessHelper.cs:314

FrontOffice.Areas.NewBusiness.Controllers.ImportFormsController.ProcessFormAddOnPremium(Int32 id) in c:\Users\hprentiss\Documents\SI Project\T3 Core\Dev\FrontOffice\Areas\NewBusiness\Controllers\ImportFormsController.cs:135

I guess these are not your own code, but that's where you may get a clue from.  If we assume `Datetime.Now` is a valid value, what about changing the `null` value to something else, just as a sanity check?

Comment: There is nothing with Datetimes there. It is NHibernate firing off an update and deciding that a null date should be a minimum.

Comment: Fair enough, but that is in fact "something with a DateTime".  Just cause it is happening within NHibernate doesn't change the nature of the exception.